# Keep ONLY nodes (siblings and parents included) that contain a specific string value

Tags: c#, xml, console-application

I'm new here, so excuse me if I'm doing this incorrectly.

I have a series of different XML documents with different XML node definitions. I'm trying to create a utilitarian console application that allows me to trim any xml file down to nodes that contain a specific string value within them.

For example this xml:

```
<CWeaponInfoBlob>
    <SlotNavigateOrder>
        <Item>
            <WeaponSlots>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="10" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_UNARMED</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="20" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_KNIFE</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="30" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_NIGHTSTICK</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="40" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_HAMMER</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="50" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_BAT</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="60" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_CROWBAR</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="70" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_GOLFCLUB</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="90" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_PISTOL</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="100" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_COMBATPISTOL</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="110" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_PISTOL50</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="120" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_APPISTOL</Entry>
                </Item>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="130" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_STUNGUN</Entry>
                </Item>
            </WeaponSlots>
        </Item>
    </SlotNavigationOrder>
</CWeaponInfoBlob>
```

I'd like to be able to pass a string to the Console like "STUNGUN", and have the program remove any "Item" nodes that don't contain that word.

I've done this successfully but not as I would like it to be. I have one hell-of-an XML file with 21,615 lines, that contain definitions for "weapons". By passing "STUNGUN" to the console, I'd like it to do the same exact thing and remove any (I guess parent??) nodes that don't have a node containing the inputted word.

[Here's my xml file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwBLT3G9VxbMTG5NbmZpbEx3Mzg)
If you search for the word "STUNGUN" you'll find multiple definitions for it, I'd like the program to keep only those nodes (**and sibling nodes!!**). How would I go about doing this?

Here's what I've tried (don't judge the code, I've never done anything like this in all my 5 years of programming, obviously it doesn't work):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;

namespace XmlUtil
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length <= 0)
                return;

            if (!args.All(i => i.EndsWith(".meta")) && !args.All(i => i.EndsWith(".xml")))
                return;

            try
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < args.Length; x++)
                {
                    var arg = args[x];

                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string value:");
                    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    var xml = new XmlDocument();
                    xml.Load(arg);
                    var nodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName("*");
                    var ienum = nodes.GetEnumerator();

                    XmlDocument newDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    while(ienum.MoveNext())
                    {
                        XmlNode node = (XmlNode)ienum.Current;
                        if (node.InnerText.Contains(userinput))
                        {
                            newDoc.ImportNode(node, false);
                        }
                    }
                    // Then write it to a file...
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I'd like to add that this one was done manually, and it took me hours to cut out the unneeded nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CWeaponInfoBlob>
    <SlotNavigateOrder>
        <Item>
            <WeaponSlots>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="191" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_SCICARBINE</Entry>
                </Item>
            </WeaponSlots>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <WeaponSlots>
                <Item>
                    <OrderNumber value="201" />
                    <Entry>SLOT_SCICARBINE</Entry>
                </Item>
            </WeaponSlots>
        </Item>
    </SlotNavigateOrder>
    <SlotBestOrder>
        <WeaponSlots>
            <Item>
                <OrderNumber value="81" />
                <Entry>SLOT_SCICARBINE</Entry>
            </Item>
        </WeaponSlots>
    </SlotBestOrder>
    <TintSpecValues />
    <FiringPatternAliases />
    <UpperBodyFixupExpressionData />
    <AimingInfos />
    <Infos>
        <Item>
            <Infos>
                <Item type="CWeaponInfo">
                    <Name>WEAPON_SCICARBINE</Name>
                    <Model>W_AR_SCICARBINERIFLE</Model>
                    <Audio>AUDIO_ITEM_RAILGUN</Audio>
                    <Slot>SLOT_SCICARBINE</Slot>
                    <DamageType>BULLET</DamageType>
                    <Explosion>
                        <Default>DONTCARE</Default>
                        <HitCar>DONTCARE</HitCar>
                        <HitTruck>DONTCARE</HitTruck>
                        <HitBike>DONTCARE</HitBike>
                        <HitBoat>DONTCARE</HitBoat>
                        <HitPlane>DONTCARE</HitPlane>
                    </Explosion>
                    <FireType>INSTANT_HIT</FireType>
                    <WheelSlot>WHEEL_RIFLE</WheelSlot>
                    <Group>GROUP_RIFLE</Group>
                    <AmmoInfo ref="AMMO_RIFLE" />
                    <AimingInfo ref="RIFLE_LO_BASE_STRAFE" />
                    <ClipSize value="30" />
                    <AccuracySpread value="3.000000" />
                    <AccurateModeAccuracyModifier value="0.500000" />
                    <RunAndGunAccuracyModifier value="2.000000" />
                    <RunAndGunAccuracyMaxModifier value="1.000000" />
                    <RecoilAccuracyMax value="0.500000" />
                    <RecoilErrorTime value="3.000000" />
                    <RecoilRecoveryRate value="1.000000" />
                    <RecoilAccuracyToAllowHeadShotAI value="1000.000000" />
                    <MinHeadShotDistanceAI value="1000.000000" />
                    <MaxHeadShotDistanceAI value="1000.000000" />
                    <HeadShotDamageModifierAI value="1000.000000" />
                    <RecoilAccuracyToAllowHeadShotPlayer value="0.175000" />
                    <MinHeadShotDistancePlayer value="5.000000" />
                    <MaxHeadShotDistancePlayer value="40.000000" />
                    <HeadShotDamageModifierPlayer value="18.000000" />
                    <Damage value="32.000000" />
                    <DamageTime value="0.000000" />
                    <DamageTimeInVehicle value="0.000000" />
                    <DamageTimeInVehicleHeadShot value="0.000000" />
                    <HitLimbsDamageModifier value="0.500000" />
                    <NetworkHitLimbsDamageModifier value="0.800000" />
                    <LightlyArmouredDamageModifier value="0.750000" />
                    <Force value="75.000000" />
                    <ForceHitPed value="140.000000" />
                    <ForceHitVehicle value="1200.000000" />
                    <ForceHitFlyingHeli value="1250.000000" />
                    <OverrideForces>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_HEAD</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="80.000000" />
                            <ForceBack value="50.000000" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_NECK</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="60.000000" />
                            <ForceBack value="90.000000" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_L_THIGH</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="40.000000" />
                            <ForceBack value="1.000000" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_R_THIGH</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="40.000000" />
                            <ForceBack value="1.000000" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_L_CALF</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="70.000000" />
                            <ForceBack value="80.000000" />
                        </Item>
                        <Item>
                            <BoneTag>BONETAG_R_CALF</BoneTag>
                            <ForceFront value="60.000000" />
                            <ForceBack value="100.000000" />
                        </Item>
                    </OverrideForces>
                    <ForceMaxStrengthMult value="1.000000" />
                    <ForceFalloffRangeStart value="0.000000" />
                    <ForceFalloffRangeEnd value="50.000000" />
                    <ForceFalloffMin value="1.000000" />
                    <ProjectileForce value="0.000000" />
                    <FragImpulse value="600.000000" />
                    <Penetration value="0.100000" />
                    <VerticalLaunchAdjustment value="0.000000" />
                    <DropForwardVelocity value="0.000000" />
                    <Speed value="2000.000000" />
                    <BulletsInBatch value="1" />
                    <BatchSpread value="0.000000" />
                    <ReloadTimeMP value="-1.000000" />
                    <ReloadTimeSP value="-1.000000" />
                    <VehicleReloadTime value="1.000000" />
                    <AnimReloadRate value="1.000000" />
                    <BulletsPerAnimLoop value="1" />
                    <TimeBetweenShots value="0.135000" />
                    <TimeLeftBetweenShotsWhereShouldFireIsCached value="-1.000000" />
                    <SpinUpTime value="0.000000" />
                    <SpinTime value="0.000000" />
                    <SpinDownTime value="0.000000" />
                    <AlternateWaitTime value="-1.000000" />
                    <BulletBendingNearRadius value="0.000000" />
                    <BulletBendingFarRadius value="0.750000" />
                    <BulletBendingZoomedRadius value="0.375000" />
                    <FirstPersonBulletBendingNearRadius value="0.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonBulletBendingFarRadius value="0.750000" />
                    <FirstPersonBulletBendingZoomedRadius value="0.375000" />
                    <Fx>
                        <EffectGroup>WEAPON_EFFECT_GROUP_RIFLE_ASSAULT</EffectGroup>
                        <FlashFx>muz_railgun</FlashFx>
                        <FlashFxAlt />
                        <FlashFxFP />
                        <FlashFxAltFP />
                        <MuzzleSmokeFx />
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxFP />
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxMinLevel value="0.000000" />
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxIncPerShot value="0.000000" />
                        <MuzzleSmokeFxDecPerSec value="0.000000" />
                        <ShellFx>eject_auto</ShellFx>
                        <ShellFxFP>eject_auto_fp</ShellFxFP>
                        <TracerFx>bullet_tracer</TracerFx>
                        <PedDamageHash>BulletLarge</PedDamageHash>
                        <TracerFxChanceSP value="0.150000" />
                        <TracerFxChanceMP value="0.750000" />
                        <FlashFxChanceSP value="1.000000" />
                        <FlashFxChanceMP value="1.000000" />
                        <FlashFxAltChance value="0.200000" />
                        <FlashFxScale value="1.000000" />
                        <FlashFxLightEnabled value="true" />
                        <FlashFxLightCastsShadows value="false" />
                        <FlashFxLightOffsetDist value="0.000000" />
                        <FlashFxLightRGBAMin x="255.000000" y="93.000000" z="25.000000" />
                        <FlashFxLightRGBAMax x="255.000000" y="100.000000" z="50.000000" />
                        <FlashFxLightIntensityMinMax x="1.000000" y="2.000000" />
                        <FlashFxLightRangeMinMax x="2.500000" y="3.500000" />
                        <FlashFxLightFalloffMinMax x="1024.000000" y="1536.000000" />
                        <GroundDisturbFxEnabled value="false" />
                        <GroundDisturbFxDist value="5.000000" />
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameDefault />
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameSand />
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameDirt />
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameWater />
                        <GroundDisturbFxNameFoliage />
                    </Fx>
                    <InitialRumbleDuration value="90" />
                    <InitialRumbleIntensity value="0.700000" />
                    <InitialRumbleIntensityTrigger value="0.950000" />
                    <RumbleDuration value="90" />
                    <RumbleIntensity value="0.100000" />
                    <RumbleIntensityTrigger value="0.800000" />
                    <RumbleDamageIntensity value="1.000000" />
                    <InitialRumbleDurationFps value="150" />
                    <InitialRumbleIntensityFps value="1.000000" />
                    <RumbleDurationFps value="95" />
                    <RumbleIntensityFps value="1.000000" />
                    <NetworkPlayerDamageModifier value="1.000000" />
                    <NetworkPedDamageModifier value="1.000000" />
                    <NetworkHeadShotPlayerDamageModifier value="1.700000" />
                    <LockOnRange value="65.000000" />
                    <WeaponRange value="120.000000" />
                    <BulletDirectionOffsetInDegrees value="0.000000" />
                    <AiSoundRange value="-1.000000" />
                    <AiPotentialBlastEventRange value="-1.000000" />
                    <DamageFallOffRangeMin value="47.500000" />
                    <DamageFallOffRangeMax value="120.000000" />
                    <DamageFallOffModifier value="0.300000" />
                    <VehicleWeaponHash />
                    <DefaultCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_AIM_CAMERA</DefaultCameraHash>
                    <CoverCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_AIM_IN_COVER_CAMERA</CoverCameraHash>
                    <CoverReadyToFireCameraHash />
                    <RunAndGunCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_RUN_AND_GUN_CAMERA</RunAndGunCameraHash>
                    <CinematicShootingCameraHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_PED_CINEMATIC_SHOOTING_CAMERA</CinematicShootingCameraHash>
                    <AlternativeOrScopedCameraHash />
                    <RunAndGunAlternativeOrScopedCameraHash />
                    <CinematicShootingAlternativeOrScopedCameraHash />
                    <CameraFov value="35.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonScopeFov value="20.00000"/>
                    <FirstPersonScopeAttachmentFov value="20.00000"/>
                    <FirstPersonRNGOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonRNGRotationOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonLTOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonLTRotationOffset x="0.000000" y="0.000000" z="0.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonScopeOffset x="0.00000" y="-0.0200" z="-0.0230" />
                    <FirstPersonScopeAttachmentOffset x="0.00000" y="0.0000" z="-0.0280" />
                    <FirstPersonScopeRotationOffset x="-0.70000" y="0.0000" z="0.0000" />
                    <FirstPersonScopeAttachmentRotationOffset x="0.00000" y="0.0000" z="0.0000" />
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonIdleOffset x="-0.07500000" y="0.000000" z="-0.05" />
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonRNGOffset x="-0.025000" y="0.000000" z="-0.075000" />
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonLTOffset x="0.025000" y="0.000000" z="-0.0750000" />
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonScopeOffset x="0.075000" y="-0.050000" z="-0.060000" />
                    <FirstPersonAsThirdPersonWeaponBlockedOffset x="-0.1000000" y="0.000000" z="-0.100000" />
                    <FirstPersonDofSubjectMagnificationPowerFactorNear value="1.025000" />
                    <FirstPersonDofMaxNearInFocusDistance value="0.000000" />
                    <FirstPersonDofMaxNearInFocusDistanceBlendLevel value="0.300000" />
                    <ZoomFactorForAccurateMode value="1.300000" />
                    <RecoilShakeHash>ASSAULT_RIFLE_RECOIL_SHAKE</RecoilShakeHash>
                    <RecoilShakeHashFirstPerson>FPS_ASSAULT_RIFLE_RECOIL_SHAKE</RecoilShakeHashFirstPerson>
                    <AccuracyOffsetShakeHash>DEFAULT_THIRD_PERSON_ACCURACY_OFFSET_SHAKE</AccuracyOffsetShakeHash>
                    <MinTimeBetweenRecoilShakes value="100" />
                    <RecoilShakeAmplitude value="0.333000" />
                    <ExplosionShakeAmplitude value="-1.000000" />
                    <ReticuleHudPosition x="0.000000" y="0.000000" />
                    <AimOffsetMin x="0.250000" y="0.200000" z="0.600000" />
                    <AimProbeLengthMin value="0.430000" />
                    <AimOffsetMax x="0.165000" y="-0.180000" z="0.470000" />
                    <AimProbeLengthMax value="0.340000" />
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSIdle x="0.162000" y="0.225000" z="0.052000" />
                    <AimOffsetMedFPSIdle x="0.187000" y="0.197000" z="0.321000" />
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSIdle x="0.155000" y="0.038000" z="0.364000" />
                    <AimOffsetEndPosMinFPSIdle x="-0.284000" y="0.612000" z="-0.205000" />
                    <AimOffsetEndPosMedFPSIdle x="-0.178000" y="0.639000" z="0.616000" />
                    <AimOffsetEndPosMaxFPSIdle x="-0.21700" y="-0.096000" z="0.887000" />
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSLT x="0.180000" y="0.231000" z="0.669000" />
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSLT x="0.048000" y="-0.225000" z="0.409000" />
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSRNG x="0.120000" y="0.275000" z="0.509000" />
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSRNG x="0.138000" y="-0.212000" z="0.518000" />
                    <AimOffsetMinFPSScope x="0.090000" y="0.078000" z="0.531000" />
                    <AimOffsetMaxFPSScope x="0.006000" y="-0.059000" z="0.694000" />
                    <TorsoAimOffset x="-1.000000" y="0.550000" />
                    <TorsoCrouchedAimOffset x="0.100000" y="0.120000" />
                    <LeftHandIkOffset x="0.230000" y="-0.001000" z="-0.052000" />
                    <ReticuleMinSizeStanding value="0.600000" />
                    <ReticuleMinSizeCrouched value="0.500000" />
                    <ReticuleScale value="0.300000" />
                    <ReticuleStyleHash>WEAPONTYPE_RIFLE</ReticuleStyleHash>
                    <FirstPersonReticuleStyleHash />
                    <PickupHash>PICKUP_WEAPON_SCICARBINE</PickupHash>
                    <MPPickupHash>PICKUP_AMMO_BULLET_MP</MPPickupHash>
                    <HumanNameHash>WT_RIFLE_CBN</HumanNameHash>
                    <MovementModeConditionalIdle>MMI_2Handed</MovementModeConditionalIdle>
                    <StatName>CRBNRIFLE</StatName>
                    <KnockdownCount value="-1" />
                    <KillshotImpulseScale value="1.000000" />
                    <NmShotTuningSet>Automatic</NmShotTuningSet>
                    <AttachPoints>
                                            <Item>
                                                <AttachBone>WAPClip</AttachBone>
                                                <Components>
                                                    <Item>
                                                        <Name>COMPONENT_SCICARBINE_CLIP_01</Name>
                                                        <Default value="true" />
                                                    </Item>
                                                </Components>
                                            </Item>
                                        </AttachPoints>
                    <GunFeedBone />
                    <TargetSequenceGroup />
                    <WeaponFlags>CarriedInHand Automatic Gun CanLockonOnFoot CanLockonInVehicle CanFreeAim TwoHanded AnimReload AnimCrouchFire UsableOnFoot UsableInCover AllowEarlyExitFromFireAnimAfterBulletFired NoLeftHandIKWhenBlocked AllowCloseQuarterKills HasLowCoverReloads HasLowCoverSwaps LongWeapon UseFPSAimIK UseFPSSecondaryMotion</WeaponFlags>
                    <TintSpecValues ref="TINT_DEFAULT" />
                    <FiringPatternAliases ref="FIRING_PATTERN_RIFLE" />
                    <ReloadUpperBodyFixupExpressionData ref="default" />
                    <AmmoDiminishingRate value="3" />
                    <AimingBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <FiringBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <StealthAimingBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <StealthFiringBreathingAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <AimingLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <FiringLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <StealthAimingLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <StealthFiringLeanAdditiveWeight value="1.000000" />
                    <ExpandPedCapsuleRadius value="0.000000" />
                    <AudioCollisionHash />
                    <HudDamage value="32" />
                    <HudSpeed value="65" />
                    <HudCapacity value="40" />
                    <HudAccuracy value="55" />
                    <HudRange value="45" />
                </Item>
            </Infos>
        </Item>
    </Infos>
</CWeaponInfoBlob>
```

Notice that the `<Item type="CWeaponInfo">` for `SCICARBINE` hasn't been removed because it has a node that **contains** the word SCICARBINE so it and it's siblings where kept.

Comment: Have you considered using Linq to XML? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml
That will allow you to treat the XML Document as just another IEnumerable and write simple queries against it. Can't write a sample now as I'm not at my computer.

Comment: Hmm, so re-construct the xml using Linq? Sounds interesting I'll have to do more research. A nice code sample would be appreciated when you get a chance! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using xml linq for 1st request

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> removeNodes = doc.Descendants("WeaponSlots").Descendants("Item").Where(x => !x.Descendants("Entry").Where(y => (string)y == "SLOT_STUNGUN").Any()).ToList();
            foreach (XElement removeNode in removeNodes)
            {
                removeNode.Remove();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

Second request

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string ADD_FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XDocument addDoc = XDocument.Load(ADD_FILENAME);

            XElement docRoot = doc.Root;
            XElement addRoot = addDoc.Root;

            foreach (XElement child in addRoot.Elements())
            {
                string elementName = child.Name.LocalName;

                XElement docElement = docRoot.Element(elementName);

                docElement.Add(child.FirstNode);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, this is starting to make sense now. I honestly don't have an issue with manually defining the descendants, as long as the nodes without my desired text get removed. @jdweng

Comment: Yep, works fine. I'll take it. Thanks!! You saved me so much time.

Comment: Added 2nd request.  Took me a few minutes to get it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Based on jdweng's answer this is what I came up with. Thanks again, guys!

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WeaponInfoTemplateGenerator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 0)
                return;

            if (!args.All(i => i.EndsWith(".meta")) && !args.All(i => i.EndsWith(".xml")))
                return;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
                {
                    var arg = args[i];
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter a string value:");
                    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(arg);
                    doc.RemoveSimilarNodes(userInput, "Entry", "SlotNavigateOrder", "Item", "WeaponSlots", "Item");
                    doc.RemoveSimilarNodes(userInput, "Entry", "SlotBestOrder", "WeaponSlots", "Item");
                    doc.ClearNode("TintSpecValues");
                    doc.ClearNode("FiringPatternAliases");
                    doc.ClearNode("UpperBodyFixupExpressionData");
                    doc.ClearNode("AimingInfos");
                    doc.RemoveSimilarNodes(userInput, "Name", "Infos", "Item", "Infos", "Item");
                    doc.ClearNode("VehicleWeaponInfos");
                    doc.Save(arg + ".new.xml");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press [Enter] to exit...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WeaponInfoTemplateGenerator
{
    public static class Util
    {

        public static void RemoveSimilarNodes(this XDocument doc, string targetStringValue, string targetDescendant, params string[] path)
        {
            // Go to the last node.
            IEnumerable<XElement> currentNode = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < path.Length; i++)
            {
                string name = path[i];
                if (currentNode == null)
                {
                    currentNode = doc.Descendants(name);
                    continue;
                }

                currentNode = currentNode.Descendants(name);
            }

            // Check the target descendant, and get it's children.
            List<XElement> navOrders = currentNode.Where(x => !x.Descendants(targetDescendant).Where(y => ((string)y).Contains(targetStringValue)).Any()).ToList();

            // Remove the nodes.
            foreach (XElement node in navOrders)
            {
                node.Remove();
            }
        }

        public static void ClearNode(this XDocument doc, string descendant)
        {
            List<XElement> desc = doc.Descendants(descendant).ToList();
            desc.DescendantNodes().Remove();
        }
    }
}
```

---